# Word Filter using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of 
my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all 
the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s 
really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it 
basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take 
some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a 
really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular 
Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge 
into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already 
very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached 
Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of 
the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end 
of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are 
very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

let storyWords = story.split(' ');
console.log(storyWords.length);

let betterWords = storyWords.includes(unnecessaryWords);
```

So there's my JavaScript code above.

This is for a class assignment. We're learning about iterators for arrays. (Basically the methods defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

What I've already done is set up a string with a story. I then made two different arrays, one with overused words and one with unnecessary words.

Then I made an array that would take the string from the variable story that saved each word and put it into a new array called storyWords.

Now I'm trying to create an array that removes the unnecessary words.  I want to Iterate over my array to filter out these words and save the remaining words in an array called betterWords.

How can I do this? We were told not to use for loops and to take advantage of the iterators we learned. I'm sure there's some sort of function I have to do to accomplish this but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Right now I'm thinking that I need to use either .filter or .includes but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: What have you tried ? You are not even trying with a simple loop. If you think that you need `filter` or `include` - Read the documentation and see if it fits

Comment: Apart from your assignment, the easier way would be a regex `let rg = new RegExp(unnecessaryWords.join(' |'), 'gmi');
let betterWords = story.replace(rg, '');`

Answer (score 3):

Use **[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** with **[Array#include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** inside it and reverse the result.

```js
let story = `Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of 
my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all 
the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s 
really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it 
basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take 
some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a 
really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular 
Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge 
into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already 
very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached 
Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of 
the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end 
of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are 
very close to the end.`;

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

let storyWords = story.split(' ');

let betterWords = storyWords.filter(sw => !unnecessaryWords.includes(sw.toLowerCase()));

console.log(betterWords);
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you using arrow syntax too.